# Ruby complex data structure intersection wildcarding

Tags: ruby

Below is an example of a single XML record; there could be 1->N person fields in each record and there are many records within `<root> ... </root>`.

I have a template that generates each entry and I'd like to re-use that template to perform the lookup (in the interests of DRY).  I was thinking that I could take an empty template, populate it with some kind of wildcard, and then perform an intersection (`&&`) between the populated template and the database.  Currently I have a lookup routine that is multiple lines of `find_all...each do` and it can become out of sync with the generation template, which is not good!

```
require 'xmlsimple'

xml = Q%(
<root>
  <location>
    <name>San Jose</name>
    <trips>
      <trip>
        <date>April 1, 2014</date>
        <person>
          <pname>Bob</pname>
          <cost>500.00</cost>
          <days>3</days>
        </person>
        <person>
          <pname>Alice</pname>
          <cost>30.00</cost>
          <days>1</days>
        </person>
      </trip>
    </trips>
  </location>
  <location>
    <name>Florida</name>
    <trips>
      <trip>
        <date>April 20, 2014</date>
        <person>
          <pname>Alice</pname>
          <cost>300.00</cost>
          <days>3</days>
        </person>
      </trip>
      <trip>
        <date>May 1, 2014</date>
        <person>
          <pname>Alice</pname>
          <cost>500.00</cost>
          <days>4</days>
        </person>
      </trip>
    </trips>
  </location>
</root>
```

)

```
>> db_hash = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml)
=> {"location"=>[{"name"=>["San Jose"], "trips"=>[{"trip"=>[{"date"=>["April 1, 2014"], "person"=>[{"pname"=>["Bob"], "cost"=>["500.00"], "days"=>["3"]}, {"pname"=>["Alice"], "cost"=>["30.00"], "days"=>["1"]}]}]}]}, {"name"=>["Florida"], "trips"=>[{"trip"=>[{"date"=>["April 20, 2014"], "person"=>[{"pname"=>["Alice"], "cost"=>["300.00"], "days"=>["3"]}]}, {"date"=>["May 1, 2014"], "person"=>[{"pname"=>["Alice"], "cost"=>["500.00"], "days"=>["4"]}]}]}]}]}
```

I want to do something (logically) like this:

```
>> match_hash = XmlSimple.xml_in(template)
=> {"location"=>[{"name"=>["*"], "trips"=>[{"trip"=>[{"date"=>["*"], "person"=>[{"pname"=>["Bob"], "cost"=>["*"], "days"=>["*"]}]}]}]}]}
>> result = db_hash && match_hash
=> {"location"=>[{"name"=>["San Jose"], "trips"=>[{"trip"=>["April 1, 2014"], "person"=>[{"pname"=>["Bob"], "cost"=>["500.00"], "days"=>["3"]}]}]}]}
```

Is it possible to use wildcards when using `&&`?

Is there a way to perform this operation generically without specifying each hash key name?

The goal is to have a single source describing the data structure organization and use that for both reading and writing.  I'm `eval`ing a template when I create a new entry and this could be used to create `template` above.

Comment: There is no built-in method to do what you want. You will need to write your own algorithm to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a templating engine. [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) seems a good fit, as it can merge ActiveRecord queries into a template.

Another option is to use the XML itself as a template. A simple Nokogiri script can replace the wildcards with text.

Comment: I scanned through the documentation and it looks like a templating engine would provide better methods for creating new entries.  However, it was not clear to me how a templating engine would provide any additional capabilities with complex searches.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Searches? Can you provide more detail on what you want to search? Is this on the database side? Or are you talking about an XPath query?

Comment: Given a defined record structure I want collect all records that match a set of query values.  My current production code uses a bunch of nested `find_all` statements that must match the record structure exactly, e.g. `xml["location"].to_a[0].to_h["name"].find_all`.  This can cause misalignment between my write methods and my query/search methods.  I was hoping that Ruby offered a way to ensure that the write and query/search methods always matched a defined template.

Comment: I can see how I could write some code to parse the template and then eval generated find_all statements.  However, this seems like a common operation and I wanted to see if someone had already solved this problem.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a common operation at all. Compound queries are better in a database of some sort, either SQL or NoSQL (e.g. MongoDB)